# How to pass props to every instance of a reused component?

Tags: reactjs

Say I have a header component, which will be reused on every single page within my site. Is there a way to pass the same props to every instance of this Header component, without having to explicitly type out the props on every instance?

For example, suppose I have a home page and a /proposecourse page. Both of these pages have the "main" component, and also a header component, like so:

```
          <Route path="/proposecourse">
            <Header />
            <Proposals />
          </Route>

          <Route exact path="/">
            <Header 
              mysky={mysky}
              loggedIn={loggedIn}
              setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn}
              setSkynetID={setSkynetID}
            />
            <Home />
          </Route>
```

As can be seen, the second instance of `Header` has many props passed to it. But the first `Header`, although the same component, does not have those props, and I cannot access them on that specific component. Is there an efficient way of passing the same props to both without retyping the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the element to a local variable, and then use that multiple times in the rendering:

```
const Example = () => {
  const header = (
    <Header
      mysky={mysky}
      loggedIn={loggedIn}
      setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn}
      setSkynetID={setSkynetID}
    />
  );
  return (
    <>
      <Route path="/proposecourse">
        {header}
        <Proposals />
      </Route>

      <Route exact path="/">
        {header}
        <Home />
      </Route>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: ooh okay. Is there no way to just say in react "this component always gets passed these props" and instead we have explicitly type the props for every instance of a component? Are there any optimization downsides to this? ie, is this only initializing the props ONCE, or creating copies of the props every time?

Comment: `Is there no way to just say in react "this component always gets passed these props"` Under the hood, a JSX tag is just a call to React.createElement, passing in some parameters (the type and props). So you're basically asking "how can i call createElement without passing in parameters, and have it know what parameters i want". You can't. You need to supply those parameters for it to do its job. My solution lets you just call createElement once, and save the results to a variable, so you at least don't have to do the call multiple times.

Comment: `Are there any optimization downsides to this? ie, is this only initializing the props ONCE, or creating copies of the props every time?` If you write `<Header mySky={mySky} loggedIn={loggedIn} /*etc*//>` multiple times, then technically you will create more props objects than you would by doing it just once and reusing the element. But this is a very small difference in performance, and not something you should focus on when optimizing performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a spread operator to avoid explicitly typing the props.

```
const myProps = {
  mysky,
  loggedIn,
  setLoggedIn,
  setSkynetID,
};

<Header {...myProps} />
```